# How is free vector a same thing as translation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, transformation

Well, I was reading [this](http://nrich.maths.org/2390/index) and according to it, a free vector is the same thing as a translation. But as far as I know a translation is a mathematical operation and free vector is a mathematical quantity, a type of vector. So, how can an operation be same thing as a quantity.? We assign operations between quantities. Right?

Comment: I would imagine they are referring to *addition by a vector*.  If you have a position vector $s$ and a desired translation $v$ then you may represent your position vector after having been translated as $s+v$.  For example, in $\Bbb R^2$ being located at $(3,2)$ and wishing to translate two units to the right you can find the new position as $(3,2)+(2,0)=(5,2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right, strictly speaking they're not the **same** thing. But there is a one-to-one structure-preserving correspondence between vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and translations $T_{\mathbf{v}}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: are there different types of one-to-one correspondence?........you here mentioned structure-preserving correspondence.

Comment: Well, for example, if you set $T_{\mathbf{v}}(\mathbf{x}) = |\mathbf{v}|^2 \mathbf{v} + \mathbf{x}$, then you also get a 1-1-correspondence, but it no longer satisfies $T_{\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{w}} = T_{\mathbf{v}} \circ T_{\mathbf{w}}$.